# MaxOS El Capitan - computer hung up due to endless Mail App error popups

Tags: macos

I recently changed gmail password but did not update on Mail app.  I am now getting endless popups every time I log in, and an uninterupptable spinning beachball of death.  I can't do anything on my admin login, the screen keeps filling up with error messages as in attached photo.  [image]

The error is:
  **Cannot Send Message** 
  Connections to host smtp.gmail.com on the default port failed.

I can not select any buttons, the computer keeps flooding with endless popups.

How do I get this to stop?

Comment: Force-quit Mail before it manages to swamp the machine, then try deleting the contents of `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.mail.savedState/` [it's an alias so don't delete the folder itself]

Comment: You can also hold the Shift key as you log in (at the login screen, after you enter your password, hold Shift as you click the arrow button to log in). This will prevent Mail from auto-opening.